# I get status code 300 while updating the space information and image

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-1.9

i have been trying to update the space information along with the images that is on the same template.I could add the content but could not update.i tried to pass slug while submitting for updated space information for updating images too but the slug is shown null. My ajax code and view was working for the add part but not for update part. I get my console.log('rent worked') printed that is inside success function but 'request.post' is not printed which is inside EditSpaceView function What might be the reason? What should i do to make it work ?

**views.py**

```
class EditSpaceView(View):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print ('edit space view',request)
        if request.POST:
            print('request.post')
            response = HttpResponse('')
            print('edited owner name is',request.POST.get('ownerName'))
            print('edited amenities',request.POST.get('amenities'))
            rental = Rental.objetcs.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
            rental.ownerName = request.POST.get('ownerName')
            rental.email = request.POST.get('email')
            rental.phoneNumber = request.POST.get('phoneNumber')
            rental.listingName = request.POST.get('listingName')
            rental.summary = request.POST.get('summary')
            rental.property = request.POST.get('property')
            rental.room = request.POST.get('room')
            rental.price = request.POST.get('price')
            rental.city = request.POST.get('city')
            rental.place = request.POST.get('place')
            rental.water = request.POST.get('water')
            rental.amenities = request.POST.get('amenities')
            rental.save()
            response['pk-user'] = rental.slug
            #response['pk-user'] = rental.pk
            print('response slug', response);
            return response

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

class EditImage(View):
    model = Rental
    template_name = 'rentals/rent_detail.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            rental = Rental.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs['slug'])
            print('rental slug',rental)
        except Rental.DoesNotExist:
            error_dict = {'message': 'Rental spae not found'}
            return self.render(request,'rentals/rent_detail.html',error_dict)
        if request.FILES:
            for file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
                print('file',file)
                image = Gallery.objects.create(rental = rental, image=file)
                print('image',image)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^edit/image/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', EditImage.as_view(), name="editImage"),
url(r'^edit/space/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', EditSpaceView.as_view(), name="editSpace"),
```

**ajax code**

```
$.ajax({
      url:'/edit/space/'+this.props.slug+'/',
      contentType: "application/json",
      data:sendData,
      type:'POST',
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr ) {
        console.log('rent worked');
        var slug = xhr.getResponseHeader('pk-user');
        console.log('slug',slug);
        $.ajax({
         url:'/edit/image/'+slug+'/',
         data:image,
         contentType:false,
         processData:false,
         type:'POST',
         mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
         success: function(data) {
           console.log('success');
         }
    });
  }
});
```

Stacktrace in server console

```
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:35] "GET /api/v1/rental/tushant-khatiwada/ HTTP/1.1" 200 963
edit space view <WSGIRequest: POST '/edit/space/tushant-khatiwada/'>
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:50] "POST /edit/space/tushant-khatiwada/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2363
Not Found: /edit/image/null/
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:51] "POST /edit/image/null/ HTTP/1.1" 404 6882
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:35] "GET /api/v1/rental/tushant-khatiwada/ HTTP/1.1" 200 963
edit space view <WSGIRequest: POST '/edit/space/tushant-khatiwada/'>
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:50] "POST /edit/space/tushant-khatiwada/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2363
```

These requests suggests that editing with `EditSpaceView` worked as expected. The `300` response is expected and due to `HttpResponseRedirect("/")` at the end of that view.

The request

```
[05/Apr/2016 02:58:51] "POST /edit/image/null/ HTTP/1.1" 404 6882
```

suggests that `slug` that you are using to build the URL for ajax request is not valid or is null. Specifically check this line,

```
var slug = xhr.getResponseHeader('pk-user');
```

Comment: what should i do with the HttpResponseRedirect('/') then ?

Comment: @Tushant, Don't think that is an error/issue. But also check why `return response` in that method is not working.

Comment: print('request.post') is also not printed in django console. only the request gets printed.

Comment: Well, its not going to the if request.POST block.

Comment: I removed the contentType and its working. Is it because my view is returning response with text/html ? The rental information gets updated but not image.The image gets further added. How can i resolve this?

Comment: @Tushant, Not sure about that.